# How to configure Eclipse text editor home key behavior

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

In Eclipse 4.4, how do you make the home key return the cursor to the first non-whitespace character on the current line, instead of the absolute start of the line?

I recently upgraded to Eclipse 4.4 Luna, after having used 3.7. Before, when using the built-in text editor, pressing the home key would toggle the cursor between the absolute start of the line and the first non-whitespace character in the line. This was very convenient since most of my text files are heavily indented code.

However, in 4.4, this behavior no longer works. The home key causes the cursor to always return to the absolute beginning of the line, which is frustrating, because that's usually not what I want.

Apparently, this is a [very old feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19738), which was supposedly implemented years ago, so I'm not sure why it would stop working now. Thinking the feature may have been disabled, I've searched all the sections of my preferences, but I can't find any way to enable it.

How do you enable this behavior in Eclipse 4.4?

Comment: Look in the Preferences in 'General > Keys' and check the Home key is bound to 'Line Start'

Answer (score 1):

This feature still exists in Eclipse 4.4, and still should be the default, too. Probably you accidentally changed it.

Under *Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors*, check "Smart caret position at line start and end". This should restore this behaviour.

[image]